# Rails 3.2: requiring different js file in application.js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

How do I require different file in application.js.erb in Rails 3.2? I tried the following but it didn't work

```
<% if Rails.env == production %>
  //= require production_config.js
<% else %>
  //= require other_config.js
<% end %>
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Answer (score 4):

Your sample will not work because `assets:precompile` is before erb translates to clean js. And you have wrong assets syntax. What is `//= require 'production_config.rb'`? May be it's `'production_config.js'`. But you shouldn't write quotes and file extenshions in assets comments.

You can write file *config.js.erb* and write in it something like this:

```
<% if Rails.env == production %>
  productionConfig();
<% else %>
  otherConfig();
<% end %>
```

In your *application.js* file write simply

```
//= require config
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but you need to include the code in your application.html.erb (inside the head action i suggest).

If you add a **production_config.js** file to your 'asset/javascript' folder, then you can add it using:

```
<% if Rails.env == production %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "production_config" %>
<% else %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "other_config" %>
<% end %>
```

make sure you **don't** call it production_config.js.coffee (these get automatically bundled) and don't add it to you application.js either.

Answer (score 0):

Sprockets require to set `//= require` statements from the file beginning, so they aren't working.

You can use ruby methods in such cases:
[sprokets github](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/1566cd10486b677d52d93c74f489ad7a8d2acd79/lib/sprockets/context.rb#L145)

Also it would be better to do it in separate file. Something like this:

application.js

```
//= require 'config'
//= require 'jquery'
```

config.js.erb

```
<% require_asset(Rails.env.production? ? 'production_config' : 'other_config') %>
```

PS another useful method is `depend_on`, it helps when your assets need to be recompiled after some other file changes

Ex. if you need some values from `rails_config` gem

```
<%
  paths = %w(config/settings.yml config/settings.local.yml config/settings)
  paths.map(&Rails.root.method(:join)).each { |full_path| depend_on(full_path) if File.exist?(full_path) }
%>
```